# Get signature from X509 certificate

Tags: c#, .net, security, certificate

I would like to verify an X509 certificate's signature using a public key from another CA X509 certificate (knowing this certificate was signed directly by this CA). I cannot add the CA certificate to the trusted root CA list on the system.

The `X509Certificate` or `X509Certificate2` both contain the hash value of the certificate (and I can retrieve it using the `GetCertHash()` method). But neither of those contain a  method to retrieve the certificate's signature. See my code below:

```
X509Certificate2 sslCert = new X509Certificate2(...);
X509Certificate2 CAcert  = new X509Certificate2(...);

var rsa = CAcert.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
rsa.VerifyHash(sslCert.GetCertHash(),CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), ???)
```

Is there some (possibly different) way of doing this?

Comment: did you manage to find a way to do this?

Comment: Nope, I had to do a work-around in the end so I don't need the signature.